# remove file extension and path from a file name in oracle query

Tags: oracle

I have file `file:/home/ist/Desktop/hdfs/MH-MP-REM-02-A.1.zip` from table `temp1` and filename `MH-MP-REM-02-A.1` from other table. I am try a `JOIN` or `INNER JOIN` query to return as filename as `MH-MP-REM-02-A.1` by comparing both value. If filename not match with file in `file:/home/ist/Desktop/hdfs/MH-MP-REM-02-A.1.zip` it return nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This gives the correct result but it should have a better solution:

```
SUBSTR(filename,INSTR(filename,'/',-1)+1,LENGTH(SUBSTR(filename,INSTR(filename,'/',-1)+1))-4)
```